# Binary search tree count returns wrong value in C++

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

Can anyone help a newbie trying to understand these simple recursive functions on a binary tree in C++?

The function sizeofTree keeps on returning NULL.

Thanks for whatever help you can offer!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <conio.h>

struct node {
    int val;
    struct node* pLeft;
    struct node* pRight;
};

struct node* newNode(int val) {
 struct node* node = new (struct node);
 node->val = val;
 node->pLeft = NULL;
 node->pRight = NULL;
 return(node);
}

struct node* insertNode(struct node* _node, int val) {
 if (_node == NULL) return (newNode(val));
    //if (val == _node->val) return NULL;  //error handling routine
 else if (val < _node->val) _node->pLeft = insertNode(_node->pLeft, val);
 else _node->pRight = insertNode(_node->pRight, val);
}

int sizeofTree(node* _node) {
 if (_node == NULL) {
  printf("For some reason, _node is evaluating to NULL.\n");  
  return(0);
 }
 else return(sizeofTree(_node->pLeft) + sizeofTree(_node->pRight));
}

int main() {
 node* root = newNode(2);
 root->pLeft = newNode(1);
 root->pRight = newNode(3);
 printf("root is: %d\n", root->val);
 printf("left leaf is: %d\n", root->pLeft->val);
 printf("right leaf is: %d\n", root->pRight->val);
 printf("The size of tree is: %d\n", sizeofTree(root));
 getch();
}
```

Comment: That function either recurses or returns a 0. No matter how many zeros you add together, you will end up with zero. Why don't you use a debugger and step through the program?

Comment: I see your logic with `sizeofTree(_node->pLeft) + sizeofTree(_node->pRight)`, but what Dan said above is right. You're not accounting for the current node that you're stopped at (which should be +1 to the tree size), so the function will always return zero.

Comment: Why are you not incrementing some `count` variable during insertion?

Comment: Thanks folks. I corrected the sizeofTree function to include counting the current node AND most importantly, I added a return value (_node) for the newNode function so it had a value to recurse. Duh!